# How to plot spectrum or frequency vs amplitude of entire audio file using python?

Tags: python, audio, spectrum, librosa

I have some audio files, I want to plot the average spectrum of the audio files like "audacity" software using PYTHON (librosa library). I can see they are plotting average frequency vs amplitude plot of the entire audio.

[image]

After that, I want to apply CNN to classify two classes of samples. Looking for suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you use [librosa.display.specshow](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html#) to plot spectrograms over time, not over the whole file. In fact, as input for your CNN you might rather use a spectrogram over time as produced by [librosa.stft](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html) or some Mel spectrogram, depending on what your classification goal is.

E.g., if you want to classify for genre, a Mel-spectrogram may be most appropriate. If you want to find out key or chords, you'll need a Constant-Q-spectrogram (CQT), etc.

That said, here's some code that answers your question:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file = YOUR_FILE
# load the file
y, sr = librosa.load(file, sr=44100)
# short time fourier transform
# (n_fft and hop length determine frequency/time resolution)
n_fft = 2048
S = librosa.stft(y, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=n_fft//2)
# convert to db
# (for your CNN you might want to skip this and rather ensure zero mean and unit variance)
D = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(S), ref=np.max)
# average over file
D_AVG = np.mean(D, axis=1)

plt.bar(np.arange(D_AVG.shape[0]), D_AVG)
x_ticks_positions = [n for n in range(0, n_fft // 2, n_fft // 16)]
x_ticks_labels = [str(sr / 2048 * n) + 'Hz' for n in x_ticks_positions]
plt.xticks(x_ticks_positions, x_ticks_labels)
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.ylabel('dB')
plt.show()
```

This leads to this output:

[image: dB for Frequencies]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Actually, I have to do some binary classification using my dataset where there are two types of sounds regular environment sound which is considered as background. And some drone sounds which some times stays on the entire time (each sound is about 20 seconds) or passing over the mics. Can you suggest elaborately how to design this model? What type of feature extraction is required? And possibly provide some sample code where it can be easily done using CNN.

Comment: The short answer is, I'd use a Mel-spectrogram and follow an approach similar to https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00298. But since this has little to do with the original question, please ask a new question. Also, if you feel that I've answered your *original* question, please accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @hendrik , How to plot amplitude against time?

Comment: Either simply plot y or use waveplot. See https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.display.waveplot.html

Comment: @ hendrik , but if I want amplitude in db scale, I should first use STFT and then amplitude_to_db as in your answer? if yes, why should I use STFT? and what does negative db mean?

Comment: Please read up on [decibel](https://www.scienceabc.com/pure-sciences/why-negative-decibels-are-a-thing.html) on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) or elsewhere or ask a new question on https://dsp.stackexchange.com The short answer is: decibel is not a unit. It (in this case) describes the log. relationship between the maximum representable energy (e.g. `1`) and the actual energy. So if your samples are on a scale of -1 to 1, any sample with `|v|=1` (`v` being the sample value) has 0 db.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy.io import wavfile

sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read('h1.wav')
samples=samples[:,0]
frequencies, times, spectrogram = signal.spectrogram(samples, sample_rate)

plt.imshow(spectrogram)
plt.pcolormesh(times, frequencies, spectrogram)

plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I want to plot average frequency vs amplitude for entire time series. Axes of the plot will be frequency vs amplitude, not time.